# Can anyone why this code is returning an "invalid syntax" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a project I am currently doing in Python 3, one of the tasks that I must do is to take in multiline input and put it into a list, each line of input itself in lists(my way of separating the different inputs; I format them in the needed data types later, but that's beyond the scope of this question); I achieve this using the following code:

```
inputs = []
i = input()
while i != '':
  inputs.append([s for s in i.split(" ")] 
  i = input()
# example for this code:
# An input such as
# "3 7 5 9
# 2 4 6 8
# 2 1 4 5"
# would end up with inputs = [["3", "7", "5", "9"], ["2", "4", "6", "8"], ["2", "1", "4", "5"]]
```

When I ran the code in full, I got the error:
`line 38 i = input() ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`(referring to the `i = input()` inside the loop.)

Can anyone explain to me why this occurs?

Answer (score 3):

You missed a close paren here:

```
inputs.append([s for s in i.split(" ")] 
             ^ opened here             ^ oops, append paren never closed
```

As a rule, when a clearly fine line claims to have a `SyntaxError`, the problem is almost always an unclosed delimiter pair on the previous line (usually parentheses).

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the parentheses on the previous line (`for .append()`). Python thinks that `i = input()` is an extension of `[s for s in i.split(" ")]` inside the parentheses, which doesn't make sense, so you get a `SyntaxError`.